# What's the difference between ことがある or ことはある?

Tags: particle-は, particle-が

In [Tae Kim's guide](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/genericnouns), he wrote a few example sentences:

1. 徹夜して、宿題すること**は**ある。
2. 一人で行くこと**は**ありません。
3. パリに行ったこと**は**ありますか。
4. お寿司を食べたこと**が**ある。
5. そういうのを見たこと**が**なかった。

In these examples, I don't really understand why some sentences use が and some use は.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these sentences on their own would permit either が or は. It is context that could force one or the other. [This question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/whats-the-difference-between-wa-%E3%81%AF-and-ga-%E3%81%8C) is worth reading if you're interested how context comes into play.